# What is the best way to iterate over an array in react?

Tags: javascript

I get something like this from api

[0, 1000], [1, 2000], [2, 1500]

where the first digit is the type and the second is the price.

And I iterated through the array like this:

```
const discountStud = discounts?.find((el) => el[0] === 1)?.filter((item) => item !== 1)
```

Is there a more elegant way? I write in React, and you can use lodash

P.S. I only need to get the price

Comment: `?.filter((item) => item !== 1)` -> `?[1]`?

Comment: @Ry- I did not understand

Comment: I think this is more of a JavaScript topic. I'd write it this way to be more semantically sound discounts?.filter(([type]) => type === 1).map(([,price]) => price)

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100 your way is very good. Is it possible to somehow remove the types with a single code, and not create copies? For example, my type is not only 1, but also 2, 3, 4

Comment: @TeenDay are you referring to the .filter? If so, it's possible to swap the "1" with a variable. e.g. discounts?.filter(([type]) => type === yourVariable)...

Comment: If you just need the price, and the first element of the inner arrays will always represent the index: `arr[type][1]`,

Comment: `const discountStud = discounts?.flatMap(item => item);`
// discountStud => [1000, 2000, 1500]